# How to undo metadata changes of a commit in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, backout

I recently grafted a changeset in a development branch into the default branch. After that, my changes went in default as desired.

But unexpectedly, there were a lot of metadata level changeset changes went in with that checkin. To elaborate,

- Several files that were present only in my development branch and not in default branch were marked as removed in default.
- Several extra lines in certain files that were present only in my development branch and not in the default branch were marked as removed in default.

Mercurial has marked certain files and lines that are not actually present in default as removed files and lines in the default branch.

Due to this, when I try to merge again with default, mercurial marks those files and lines are removed from default and it tries to remove the same from my branch.

I tried backout to revert my problematic commit alone. Unfortunately, backout only changes the source code lines modified during checkin, but doesn't remove the metadata marking of removing the unavailable files and lines.

Is there anyway to undo the commit metadata level changes that happened undesirably? Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That behaviour is not what mercurial does by default and is generally not reproducable. You should provide a test case which actually demonstrate the claimed behaviour. `graft` only copies the changeset and does not copy information which are not part of that very changeset being grafted: https://paste.openttdcoop.org/pdpucmoml

Comment: @planetmaker Yes, I understand that it is not the default behaviour and when I tried to repeat the same process again, its not reproducible. Hence I am unable even to demonstrate the explained behaviour :(

Comment: Did you maybe do the merge the wrong way, telling your merge tool to mostly keep stuff from the 'wrong' side?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bad commit and just want to forget it ever happened, *and that commit has no descendants*, you can just do `hg strip` to remove it from history entirely (requires [strip extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension)).

If the commit does have descendants, you can use `hg histedit` (requires [histedit extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension)) to drop the changesets you don't want to keep.

Both these solutions involve editing history, which is risky if you've distributed the bad commit publicly.  You will have to coordinate with everyone who may have pulled the bad commit or any of its descendants, which isn't always possible (e.g. in an open source environment).  You will also need to redo these changes server-side, since Mercurial's `push --force` is not like Git's `push --force`.

If you don't want to edit history, you can graft the descendants of the bad commit onto the last known good ancestor (e.g. `hg up good_ancestor; hg graft 'bad_commit:: - bad_commit'`), then do `hg commit --close-branch` at the bad head(s).  Be sure to leave an informative commit message on the close-branch commit, so that other developers will know where to rebase anything that descends from the bad commit.